# Criar função global em AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou trabalhando com $mdToast que é usado em vários locais para notificação.

Gostaria de criar uma função global para ele, que seria algo assim:

```js
function alerta(texto){
               $mdToast.show(
                $mdToast.simple()
                .content(texto)
                .theme("success-toast")
                .position('bottom right')
                .hideDelay(2000)
               );
  }

// dentro de um ctrl qualquer, eu chamar ela assim:
alerta(texto);
```

Até que ponto isso é possivel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um serviço que forneça esta função, é a angular way de se fazer algo do tipo.

```
angular.factory('meuServico', meuServicoFunction);
function meuServicoFunction($mdToast) {
  var serviceInstance = {
     mostrar : mostrar
  };
  function mostrar(texto) {
     $mdToast.show(
                $mdToast.simple()
                .content(texto)
                .theme("success-toast")
                .position('bottom right')
                .hideDelay(2000)
               );
   }
   return serviceInstance;
}
```

Desta maneira, basta injetar `meuServico` no módulo primeiro, e depois no controlador que você quer utilizar e efetuar a chamada como `meuServico.mostrar('Conteudo da mensagem')`.

Answer (score 2):

Possível, é. Não quer dizer que seja recomendável, pois você perde contexto.

Assumindo que o *provider* `$mdToast` é fornecido por um módulo chamado `mdToast`:

```
var injector = angular.injector('mdToast');
var show = injector.get('show');

var msg = injector.get('simple')()
            .content(texto)
            .theme("success-toast")
            .position('bottom right')
            .hideDelay(2000);

show(msg);
```

A resposta do Ricardo provê o melhor modelo de implementação para o seu caso, um *service*.

Porém tenha em mente que toda vez que você invocar o método `angular.injector()` uma nova instância de `injector` será criada.

Answer (score 0):

Isso não deve funcionar, pois `$mdToast` irá ficar fora do contexto.

Acredito que seja ideal vc criar uma classe base abstrata, e então sua controller extender essa base. E nesta abstração vc implementa esse metodo `alerta(texto)`.

baseCtrl.js

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    var controllers;
    (function (controllers) {
        var AppCtrl = (function () {
            function AppCtrl($mdToast) {
                // construtor ...
                this.alerta = function(texto) {
                    this.$mdToast.show($mdToast.simple()
                        .content(texto)
                        .theme("success-toast")
                        .position('bottom right')
                        .hideDelay(2000));
                }
            }
            return AppCtrl;
        })();
        controllers.AppCtrl = AppCtrl;
    })(controllers = app.controllers || (app.controllers = {}));
})(app || (app = {}));
```

mainCtrl.js

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
var app;
(function (app) {
    var controllers;
    (function (controllers) {
        var MainCtrl = (function (_super) {
            __extends(MainCtrl, _super);
            function MainCtrl($scope, $mdToast) {
                _super.call(this, $mdToast);
                this.$scope = $scope;
                this.$mdToast = $mdToast;

                // Construtor da controller...

            }
            MainCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$mdToast"];
            return MainCtrl;
        })(controllers.AppCtrl);
        app.mainApp.controller("mainCtrl", MainCtrl);
    })(controllers = app.controllers || (app.controllers = {}));
})(app || (app = {}));
```

Assim, vc pode fazer todas suas controllers herdarem de AppCtrl, e todas podem consumir o metodo que dispara o $mdToast.

Como disse, não testei, mas a ideia é essa.